# Datetimepicker returns empty rows upon search in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

Trying to make a Query to Query a Database and return the rows using the DatetimePicker in C# Winform. It returns a very empty row when i click the date.

My code looks like this

```
    private void dateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT CAST(visit_date AS DATE) AS VISIT_DATE WHERE visit_date='" + dateTimePicker.Value.Date + "'";

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: @mjwills NO! this is different. This uses DateTime

Comment: I humbly suggest you need to read it. Because once you fix that issue your query will likely work. And you will no longer be open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `DateTimePicker` selects a `Date`(without time) but in the database you store the appointments with time. If you want all appointments at that date you have to use `vistidate >= @datestart and visitdate < DATE_ADD(@datestart, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`.

Note that you should also always use sql parameters to prevent sql injection and conversion issues.

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM vms_db.waiting_appointments 
               WHERE vistidate >= @datestart
                 AND visitdate < DATE_ADD(@datestart, INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@datestart",  MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker.Value.Date;
```

Comment: Works 100% Thank you so much!